# Как присвоить CSS - значение переменной в jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Как присвоить CSS - значение переменной в jQuery?

Попытка выполнения вот такого кода в .js файле не проходит компилятором:

```
    var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;

$("#bg").css({
    'height': height; //ошибка показывает сюда, на переменную **height**
    'width': width;
});
```

А как правильно сделать? В интернете даются примеры только стандартных значений. Как присвоить переменную не пишется.

Comment: Минус вопросу — учите элементарные основы Яваскрипта. Ну нельзя же по каждой мелочи создавать топик.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точку с запятой уберите в перечислении свойств.

```
$('#bg').css({
    'height': height,
    'width': width
});
```

Comment: а вот то что я width и height определил вначале, то они всем ниже идущим блокам подойдут, правильно? Т.е внизу где бы я ни указал height, то они будут принимать его значения. Так?

Comment: В большинстве случаев - да, значения переменных можно использовать нижу по коду. Но исключения так же надо учитывать. Дабы не повторяться, посмотрите комментарии к [этому вопросу](http://hashcode.ru/questions/217931/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-javascript).